# Golem Task respons back with runtime error 2, can't determine the cause

Tags: python-3.x, docker, yagna

Repo for all code I've been using is updated [here](https://github.com/ControlCplusControlV/Golem-Image-Classifier) . When I run the requestor script it exits with a runtime error 2 (File not found). I am not sure how to further debug this or fix it. So far I've converted my code over to a python slim docker image to better mirror the example. It also works for me when I spin up a docker image that typing and running "/golem/work/imageclassifier.py --trainmodel" works from root. I switched all my code to use absolute paths. I also did make sure the shebang (#!) uses linux end of file characters rather than windows before which was giving me errors. Fixed a bug where my script returns error code 2 when called with no args to now pass.

```python
    clf.fit(trainDataGlobal, trainLabelsGlobal)
    pkl_file = "classifier.pkl"
    with open(pkl_file, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(clf, file)
```

is the only piece I could think of that causes the issue, but as far as I can tell this is the proper way to pickle something in python. Requestor script is also heavily based on the simple service example and I tried to mirror my design to that. I just need help in getting more information while debugging, or guidance on how to move forward from here